# Android & Fragments

Tags: android, exception, android-fragments

To cut is short: I will present you a abstract version of my problem, so I have:
- 1 Activity, 1 main.xml with 1 FrameLayout as a container (ID = main_container)
- Fragment A, B (A is a bit more complex)

I can insert any fragment A or B in main_container, without any problems. I also can do some fragment replacing B,A,B,A (when I do the last swap it fails!) or A,B,A (again it fails at the last one)

To give you a idea of my android skills, I always do:

```
 FragmentX newX = FragmentX.newInstance(..); 
 FragmentTransaction ft ..
 ft.replace(R.id.main_container, newX);
 //ft.addToBackStack(null);
 ft.commit();
```

So the error I receive:

```
"E/AndroidRuntime(2559): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
...
E/AndroidRuntime(2559):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)"
```

Is there something wrong with this aproach? Do you need to recycle fragments, because as you see I always use the newInstance() static method? Or do you think the problem is elsewhere?

==== UPDATE ====
It turns out that my situation was like this:
fragment A (the complex one :)) inflated a fragment_A.xml which had inside 2 fragment tags, for which I did had 2 Fragment classes defined..

Anyways I made the modication of removing the 2 fragment tags from fragment_A.xml and using 2 include tags..and using just one big fragment class :(.

And now it works just fine, but in my mind previous form shoud have worked to.

Comment: Do you use Android 3+ or the compatibility jar?

Comment: Only a hunch, but if you use the compatibility jar, make sure you use the LayoutInflater passed into onCreateView(), do not create your own.

Comment: im using 3+ & I yes it is the LayoutInflater passed as param in onCreateView

Comment: Post the XML file where the error is happening. Looks like you are using fragment from inside the XML.

Comment: im closing the topic, but if anyone has explanations, please share